# Linux device tree can't find an element declared right above it

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree

I am writing a new device tree for an i.MX6 processor, trying to add a Microchip KSZ9893 Gigabit device, but the device tree can't seem to find a blob right above it.  I added an eth0 device which is a fixed link device, and tried to connect it to port 3 on the Microchip switch, but when I try to add the port assignment on the switch, I get that it can't find node eth0.

The error text:

```
|   DTC     arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl-fhab.dtb
| Error: /home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/kernel/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-fhab-common.dtsi:131.1-6 Label or path eth0 not found
| FATAL ERROR: Syntax error parsing input tree
| scripts/Makefile.lib:317: recipe for target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl-fhab.dtb' failed
| make[3]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6dl-fhab.dtb] Error 1
| arch/arm/Makefile:343: recipe for target 'imx6dl-fhab.dtb' failed
```

Here is the relevant portions of the device tree source:

specific application board dtsi (imx6qdl-fhab-common.dtsi from the error message):

```
&eth0 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet>;
    phy-reset-gpios = <&gpio1 25 1>;
    phy-reset-duration = <1000>;
    phy-reset-post-delay = <10>;
    status = "okay";

    fixed-link {
        speed = <1000>;
        full-duplex;
    };
};

&ecspi1 {
    ads7868: adc {
            compatible = "mi,shab-adc";
            reg = <0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <2000000>;
    };

    ksz9477: ksz9477@1 {
        compatible = "microchip,ksz9893";
        reg = <1>;
        spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
        spi-cpha;
        spi-cpol;

        ports {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            port@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                label = "lan1";
            };
            port@1 {
                reg = <1>;
                label = "lan2";
            };
            port@2 {
                reg = <2>;
                label = "cpu";
                ethernet = <&eth0>;
            };
        };
    };
```

It includes a common dtsi for all our application boards.  This is the one that sets up the SPI device and the RGMII pins.  I can post that if needed.

I have tried a couple different names, not setting the status on the fixed link, removing the reset line, and a few things like that to no avail.

I am running Yocto Zeus and a 4.14.149 kernel.  I have backported the driver (which I don't know if it was successful yet) from the 5.1 kernel.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ethernet controller in imx6 is FEC, so you should use `&fec1` or respective ethernet controller. If you want to use as `eth0`, then need alias.

Comment: I didn't realize that those names had meanings, I thought they were just names.  If you write this as response, I can select it.  I copied the eth0 from the newer kernel documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to add a few things:

The names do have meanings to some extend. Take a look at the core [devicetree file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl.dtsi) of the imx6 SoM. This file descirbes the common features of the imx6 family. SoM's like the imq6q (quad core) and imx6dl (dual core) include and further specify the hardware. In line 1038 of the imx6qdl.dtsi file, there is a device node named fec declared with the compatible flag "fsl,imx6q-fec" and some interrupts + bus descriptions:

```
fec: ethernet@2188000 {
    compatible = "fsl,imx6q-fec";
    reg = <0x02188000 0x4000>;
    interrupt-names = "int0", "pps";
    interrupts-extended =
        <&intc 0 118 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>,
        <&intc 0 119 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_ENET>,
        <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_ENET>,
        <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_ENET_REF>;
    clock-names = "ipg", "ahb", "ptp";
    status = "disabled";
};
```

So this device "fec" descirbes this particular node at the address 2188000 for which the imx6q-fec driver will be loaded (later, you'll refer to it as eth0 which can be defined, as you mentioned earlier, in the alias section).

You always can override and add new attributes to existing nodes when you reference them (&-sign before the name). Referencing non-existing nodes result in the error from your question as far as I know.

But back to the topic:

You could write a patch for the imx6qdl.dtsi file I linked above and rename the fec node in line 1038 to be eth0. From this point on every component want to reference this particular ethernet NIC must reference &eth0 instead of &fec (which will result in dts compiler errors all around the imx6 eco system).

Another notable thing I had to learn the hard way: You, for example, want to use UART and wire your hardware to the pins for UART2, you need to add the pinmux group to the pinctrl-0 node of the correct uart. Let's take a look at the [imx6qdl-phytec-mira.dtsi](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-phytec-mira.dtsi) file (line 226):

```
&uart2 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart2>;
    status = "okay";
};
```

Here &pinctrl_uart2 node in the pinmux section describes the pins which are being connected to the uart2 interface of the chip itself (line 345):

```
pinctrl_uart2: uart2grp {
    fsl,pins = <
        MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_D26__UART2_TX_DATA   0x1b0b1
        MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_D27__UART2_RX_DATA   0x1b0b1
    >;
};
```

If you try to connect the pins for UART2 singals to another uart device, the communcation won't work since you only can multiplex pads for the same device (if it makes sense). There are always multiple UART2 pads available.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Parthiban in the comments on the original question.:

The names in the device tree have meaning, and apparently on the i.MX6 the ethernet device is a node called fec, so the ethernet needed to match the name.  Because of this, I couldn't name it eth0 (which came from the kernel documentation).

If I wanted to name it eth0 anyways, I would need to set up an alias.